# Best approach for drop down navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, soundcloud

I currently have this navigation bar, made from CSS and HTML, mostly inline-block elements:

[image: NAVIGATION BAR]

What I want to achieve is the same affect as this navigation menu on [SOUNDCLOUD](http://www.soundcloud.com)

Where the menu drops down once you click n item in the navigation, to obviously give you more options and increase navigation space. Here is the state I wish to achieve:

[image: SOUNDCLOUD MENU]

As i've got the basic HTML & CSS, what would be the next best step in terms of functionality.

Anyone know of any similar JQuery that would accomodate this type of interaction?

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Sounds like you need jQuery's `.slideToggle();` [.slideToggle() - jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need anything too fancy.  Basic jQuery will do it.  Check out this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eDx3W/)

Here's the basic idea:  a clickable link that animates another div into visibility -- just that in your HTML/CSS layout, the div is above the clicked element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reveal').click( function() {
        $('#hidden').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you havn't provided any HTML, I have made some up as an example:

```
<div id="dropdown" style="display:none;">
<!-- slideToggle() finishes with display:none when hiding an element. specifying display:none beforehand simply makes it so that the element is hidden when the page loads. -->

    <!--Content here-->
</div>

<div class="navigationbar">
    <div class="button" id="more"></div>
<div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#more').click(function(){
            $('#dropdown').slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!